# Spring Rest Service throwing HTTP Status 415

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am trying to call a Spring rest service from angular but I am getting the below error. Even from The Postman I am getting the same error.It looks like something is wrong with the rest service, which is not accepting the json request data
**HTTP Status 415 : The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.** Thanking everyone in advance.

Below is the code

```
**Angular Code**
var req = {
                     method: 'POST',
                     url: 'http://localhost:9050/FastTrackALM/retrieveData/getEpicData',
                     headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                     },
                     data: {'epicId': '1' }
                    }

                    $http(req).then(function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }, function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    });


**REST SERVICE**
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, 
                    value="/getEpicData",
                    consumes={"application/json"},
                    produces={"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public DataActionObject insertStudentDetails(@RequestBody epicForm1 student){
        DataActionObject dataActionObject = new DataActionObject();
        dataActionObject=epicBusinessBean.getEpicData(student.getEpicId(), dataActionObject);
        return dataActionObject;
    }
```

DataActionObject  is my custom class that holds the json date to be returned to client along with message an code

Comment: You are calling `getEpicData/1` and your controller mapping shows only `getEpicData`. You should've got 404 error.

Comment: you are passing id as well i believe with post request?

Comment: Corrected the Angular code

Comment: Serialise the javascript object before sending it. `data: JSON.stringify({'epicId': '1' })`

Comment: @AnirbanDeb What was the correction in Angular 2 post request?  I am getting the same error